# Are all jobs offered in Careers 2.0 are "from home"?

Tags: support, jobs

Typically, when visiting SO, I see the below ad:

[image]

that states `Work. From home.` Clicking it navigates to [Careers 2.0 main page](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/). Are all offered jobs listed there *actually do permit (or compel)* working from home?

Comment: The fact all job entries indicate a geographic location might have made me feel the contrary of the ad.

Comment: Yes, all jobs listed that are applicable to those dogs are work from home jobs.

Comment: Is there any chance anybody has the analogous one with the fluffy cat sitting at the computer? I'm hunting for it but my F5-key can't take much more. ( Original one of the dog: http://imgur.com/JwVhZE0 )

Comment: Nevermind. I FOUND the cat one! Here are both originals, dog and cat: http://imgur.com/a/p7uhP

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is no. I found out there's [another URL for remote jobs](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs/remote).

You can get there by checking the `Work remotely` check-box in the `search jobs` section in the [regular/all jobs search page](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs).

Funny thing is that I accidentally (or is it?) stumbled upon another ad, with no text at all, that look so:

[image]

which directed me straight to the available remote jobs list. That's a questionable choice of ads-to-content bindings...